# What type of gloves should be worn when dealing with cacti?

Tags: cactus, gloves

What type of gloves should be worn when dealing with cacti?  Standard gardening gloves seem to offer little protection.  Leather work gloves offer more protection, but end up attracting and collecting smaller spines that might cause skin irritation.

Comment: A related question http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/3006/562

Comment: I came across that - I'm more interested in general maintenance of lots of variety of cacti, although it's starting to seem like there isn't a general-purpose glove solution for this type of work.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of the cacti, I would consider Rose Gardening gloves.  They have a much longer guard and protect well against spines.  The smoother goatskin gloves would probably not collect the smaller spines. They are usually washable, but I would suggest not washing them in your clothes washer... that could get really uncomfortable.